# How to specify the FROM field for Autoresponder emails in chat Livezilla?

Tags: chat, auto-responder

Please tell me how to specify the field `FROM` for Autoresponder emails.
I pointed email here:

```
User Management -> Group -> Tickets -> Outgoing Emails -> Email sender name -> Custom
```

But the field `FROM` for Autoresponder emails has not changed. Letters come with "Mailbox" in the `FROM` field.